# i have a function and i just wanted to trigger it when i scrolled to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my jQuery function:

```
$(".count").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("Counter", 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 6e3,
        easing: "swing",
        step: function(e) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(e));
        }
    });
}),
```

I wanted to trigger it when i scrolled to the element bellow

```
<section id="counter">
    <div>
        <h3 class="count">325</h3>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your code to function at first

```
 function Foo () {
      // ....
 }
```

And then must something do this:

```
 $(function () {
      // Get element for checking scroll
      var $el = $('h3[class=count]');

      // Get Y position of this element
      var y_pos = $el.offset().top;

      // Check this on scroll
      $(window).on('scroll' function () {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > y_pos) {
                Foo();
           }
      });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function on document ready stage like

```
if ($(window).height() < 805) {
$(".count").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("Counter", 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 6e3,
        easing: "swing",
        step: function(e) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(e));
        }
    });
}),
}
```